# How to create a popup for edit button in JSF page in jDeveloper 12c?

Tags: jsf, popup, oracle-adf

How to create a popup for edit button in JSF page in Oracle jDeveloper 12c?

Comment: Don't ask here How from scratch.Search and find out and try you may fail then come here and ask why.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about JDeveloper 12c when it comes to working with popups. You can see a sample here that automatically migrates to 12c:

http://andrejusb.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/crud-operations-in-oracle-adf-11g-table.html

Comment: i have created based on the above link but OK & Cancel buttons are not in Active to click.what may be the problem

Comment: <oracle.adf.view> <PartialResponseUtils> <handleError> <ADF_FACES-60096:Server Exception during PPR, #3> 
javax.el.ELException: //C:/Users/InnfodelDev1/AppData/Roaming/JDeveloper/system12.2.1.0.42.151011.0031/o.j2ee/drs/Innfodel/ViewControllerWebApp.war/zone.jsf @41,87 popupCanceledListener="#{ZoneEdit.editPopupCancelListener}": java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: sir ,i am facing this error while running ,is there any way to overcome

Comment: Check your method ZoneEdit.editPopupCancelListener, this is throwing NPE. Any person writing ADF should have minimal Java skills to spot a NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop popup onto the form from component palette. Design as needed. Make note of popup ID. D&D Operation (from component palette) > Show Popup Behavior onto button. Set popup id to id of previously created popup. Select method to launch, like action. Google is your friend here. Search "ADF Popup" - lots of hits, like [this](https://technology.amis.nl/2011/07/28/adf-11g-show-pdf-in-a-popup/). Remember to upvote those of us who take time to help you here.